# Azure DevOps - Pass MSBuild properties as parameters to other build tasks

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, msbuild-task

In Azure DevOps, is it possible to export few MSBuild properties defined in MSBuild Tasks during the build task and use these as variables for the other tasks in the build job?

---

*Use case: Version number computed during build*

We have created a MSBuild task that as a part of the build determines version number from the git tag. The MSBuild task uses this to set the assembly versions as well as for the possible nuget packages packaged as a part of the build.

Now when setting up the Azure DevOps build pipeline I have a separate step for building an installer for the service (.msi using Advanced Installer). **I need to get the version determined during the MSBuild task and pass it for the Advanced Installer build task**, so it can be versioned accordingly. How can this be achieved?

---

As a workaround we've been previously using separate build task where the version has been determined using bash script. And then exported into VSO variable and passed to both tasks, *MSBuild* and *Advanced Installer build* (the MSBuild task can use predefined property for the version value). Now I'd like to get rid of the duplicate way of computing the version.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you don't turn off msbuild's console logging, you can use [logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/942c77ee610f753e959b3e3afc5acd715865da1d/docs/authoring/commands.md) inside your csproj file:

```
<Target Name="SetAzureDevOpsVariables" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Importance="high"
           Text="##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProductVersion]$(Version)" />
</Target>
```

`$(Version)` will be substituted by msbuild with the value of the property (you can use `PackageVersion`, `FileVersion` etc.) and the agent will interpret the command from MSBuild's output. `Importance="high"` will ensure that the message is printed even when the log verbosity is reduced.

Note that you can also put a `Condition="'$(SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID)' != ''"` on the `<Target>` element to only run this output on Azure DevOps builds.

Comment: Great. Almost knew this, but didn't realize that Azure Devops watches for the standard output and thus logging commands work also outside script tasks. 

Was hoping to find a solution that does not effect to the codebase though. In the other hand in our case we do have the control over the MSBuild task determining the versions so will definitely consider applying this approach there.

Comment: you can also put it into a `Directory.Build.targets` files in the root directory or drop an extension target into a project extension like `obj\projectfile.csproj.customext.targets` during the build.

Comment: Applied this approach by adding a task (using [File Crator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.build-task#overview)) to insert `Directory.Build.targets` with similar task you suggested.